# How to include the full path in Elastic Beanstalk logs published to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have an Elastic Beanstalk application and we configure it to automatically publish rotated logs to S3.

In an older deployment of this application, the published logs included the full path, with slashes replaced with underscores, like "_var_log_nginx_rotated_access.log1640678462.gz".

In a new deployment the published logs instead look like "access.log1644962462.gz", without the complete path.

The older deployment ran on the (now deprecated) platform "Tomcat 8.5 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux", and the newer deployment runs on the platform "Tomcat 8.5 with Corretto 11 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2".

Is there any configuration which will allow the published S3 logs to include the full path?

Answer (score 1):

I have one alternative suggestion, you can use post-processing in a Lambda to copy them to any bucket structure you want.

I referred the below link for moving specific logs to specific bucket :
..
https://medium.com/@ravindueranga/aws-elastic-beanstalk-rotated-logs-into-a-separate-s3-bucket-using-aws-lambda-cd3868447b04
..

I hope the information is useful to you as well.